# gcloud deploy does not upload new files

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I just stumbled on the following issue in App Engine Standard with a Python 2.7 enviroment

So I deployed to my test environment yesterday and today I had the idea of updating one of my applications. I do my normal "gcloud deploy ... " and it says updating 3 files ... While I actually changed a bunch of files. Basically my deploy command says the files are not changed.

After some searching around I found that files are being uploaded to a staging area and checked with a hash. Is it safe to actually clear this staging area, or does the gcloud command have some secret force option to actually force the files to be renewed.

The gcloud command has not given any errors what so ever, nor was it aborted at some point of deployment or something. So I have no errors, but my files aren't uploaded at all. I also tried modifying alot of files, and nothing changed

I never use the promote option for these rare cases that a deploy might fail

So anyone encountered this before, or has a solution to this issue ?

Comment: What type of file are you expecting to see there? `.py` files? Also, are you using [a .gcloudignore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) file?

Comment: When you run `gcloud app deploy` all the files, where you run the command, will be uploaded to the staging bucket. You can check the contents of the files but this bucket is managed by GAE, you should not delete the files within. Can you confirm if the version of your app is getting updated, when you make the deployment?

Answer (score 2):

I also was encountering this and the only solution I could find was to deploy to a new bucket. To do this:

1. go to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser and create a new bucket
2. redeploy using `gcloud app deploy --bucket gs://your-new-bucket`. (Change `your-new-bucket` to the actual bucket name)

This uploaded all the files again and created a new version in App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser and delete your application bucket, on the next deploy it will be recreated. Additionally you can use the parameter --verbosity=info to check which files are being uploaded.

Comment: the `--verbosity=info ` list outs the location of all the files and their corresponding images which allows you to delete any file that you want